# What is a good alternative to use assignment in map function in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

It is illegal to use assignment in map function, such as

```
map(lambda in: test[in]+=value[in], somelist)
```

So what is a good alternative for it. You could use for loop to do this, but it seems to me when facing large scale, the for loop solution is very slow, is there a better way?

Comment: A `for` loop will not be *that* much slower than `map()` or the equivalent comprehension (neither of which should not be used for side effects as you are attempting to do here). Hell, `map()` with `lambda` will probably be slower than a normal `for` loop.

Comment: How do you know a loop is slow, why would map be faster, and do you have a valid example?

Comment: @JoshLee I am actually not sure that map will be faster than loop, but I do experiments to compare for loop in C and in Python, found Python's for loop is very slow, so I thought there should be some ways to optimize that...

Answer (score 5):

Use this, it's preferred:

```
for i in somelist:
    test[i] += value[i]
```

And anyway, your example is *not* a good case for using `map`. You use `map` or even better, list comprehensions, when you want to create a new list as a result. In this case an assignment is being performed over each item, so there's no point in creating a new list here!

Comment: +1. This is the best, and clearest, general solution for this kind of thing.

Comment: Is it a bad case because making assignments inside `map` & `reduce` is contrary to their functional-programming nature?  Or do I not get functional programming (likely).

Comment: In pure functional programming you never use assignments. Well, one-time-assignments at worst, but not mutation of values as in this example.

Comment: The issue with using `map()` or list comps/gen exps for side effects is that they are designed to build up lists/generators, not to perform loops. This could seriously mess with your behaviour from 2.x to 3.x, where you need to exhaust `map()` to make those side effects happen.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using `numpy` (and I don't see why you would), then this should be *a lot* more performant:

```
test[somelist] += value[somelist]
```

assuming you have first converted your lists to `numpy` arrays (negligible overhead):

```
import numpy as np
test = np.array(test)
value = np.array(value)
```

Note that this would also work with the pure assignment operator `=`, besides `-=`, `*=` etc.